# Can we add attributes to standard function declarations without breaking standard?

Tags: c, posix, glibc

I wonder if adding attributes to a C method will break standard compliance or not.
Because in glibc 2.38, a `nonnull` attribute is added to `fclose()` and `freopen()` like this:

```
extern int fclose (FILE *__stream) __nonnull ((1));
```

In C++, this change is a headache as well because all following lines creates a warning now:

```
std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&fclose)> fptr(fp, fclose);
```

But there is no such attribute in POSIX standard. I wonder if adding this attribute by glibc breaks POSIX compliance. Any idea?

Comment: Generally, with a few exceptions, any symbol starting with an underscore is supposed to be implementation and compiler specific. With that said, if you need help solving the warning then please create a [mre], and copy-paste it together with the full and complete build log from that example into the question.

Comment: As for `__nonnull` itself it's likely a macro, and I'm guessing that `__nonnull((1))` will expand to `__attribute__((nonnull ((1))))`. `__attribute__` are originally GCC specific things, but many of them have been implemented by Clang as well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes probably. I can solve that C++ warning by disabling it locally (it is about the fact that attributes are not processed for template arguments). But I wondered that adding this line to a POSIX function is correct generally or not. So from your point, since `__` is compiler specific, adding this attibutes will not break POSIX.

Comment: Sidenote: You are taking the address of a function in the standard library. Don't do that unless the function is on the list of [Designated addressable functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Addressing_restriction).

Comment: Do you still get the warning if you do [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Y78Eha51W) instead?

Comment: A hack using full ISO standard C might be `extern int fclose (FILE __stream[static 1])` though I haven't tried it and I'm not sure if `FILE` likes that since it is an opaque type. You need newer versions of gcc with `-Wall` or clang to compile this with warnings.

Comment: This is all a red herring. The real question is whether the contract for `fclose` requires a valid pointer. While I only have access to the defunct n1570, it does say **7.21.5.1 The fclose function/p2**: *A successful call to the `fclose` function causes the stream pointed to by stream to be flushed and the associated file to be closed.* - this reads to me like a non-null pointer is assumed (because the - normative to my understanding - text talks of *the* stream as though it *does* exist). Since breaking a contract with the standard library has undefined behavior the attribute would be kosher

Comment: Furthermore, POSIX doesn't seem to address null pointers: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/ - It too speaks of *the* stream in the extensions. So I'd wager this doesn't violate any POSIX contracts either.

Comment: @Lundin I guess it's OK if the opaque `FILE` type is a *complete* object type. The standard does not require that, so your concerns are justified!

Comment: @IanAbbott Iirc some common implementations implement it as a regular struct and others as an opaque type, so I'm pretty certain there are standard libs where it won't be feasible. One can just try `sizeof(FILE)` and see if it compiles.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, but a regular struct could be opaque too, even if it is complete. The complete struct type presented by the API could be a facade for the actual complete struct type used by the implementation of that API, as long as the size and alignment match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When compiling with `gcc` or `g++` (or `clang`/`clang++`), the new declaration with the `__nonnull` macro in glibc 2.38 is expanded to

```c
extern int fclose (FILE *__stream) __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1)));
```

These compilers can handle the non-standard `__attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1)))`. For a compiler that can't handle that attribute, `__nonnull` ultimately expands to nothing.

However, when compiling this line

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&fclose)> fptr(fp, fclose);
```

then `g++` emits this warning:

```
 warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘int (*)(FILE*)’ [-Wignored-attributes]
std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&fclose)> fptr(fp, fclose);
```

and you'll get the same warning even if you package `fclose` in a function where you provide the same attribute using the C++ `[[attribute]]` syntax on a free function:

```cpp
[[gnu::nonnull(1)]] int closer(std::FILE* fp) {
           // (1) may be omitted since there's only one argument to the function
    return std::fclose(fp);
}
```

Both [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97222) and [clang](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=47674) have bug reports about this, but fixing it would involve an ABI addition *"Due to the way templates cause name managling to come into play"*, so the attribute is dropped and is not part of the *Deleter* type. The gcc report is in status SUSPENDED.

Since `std::fclose` is not on the list of [designated addressable functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Addressing_restriction), you should never take its address directly. Either you put the `std::fclose` call in a function like above and live with the warning - or package the call in a functor

like a lambda:

```cpp
auto closer = [] (std::FILE* fp) [[gnu::nonnull]] { std::fclose(fp); };
std::unique_ptr<std::FILE, decltype(closer)> fptr(fp, closer);
```

or in a user-defined type:

```cpp
struct closer {
    [[gnu::nonnull]] void operator()(std::FILE* fp) const {
        std::fclose(fp);
    }
};
// ...
std::unique_ptr<std::FILE, closer> fptr(fp);
```

and with that, the warning goes away since the attribute is not on the type supplied but on the call operator.

Of course, if you are willing to skip the potential optimization given by supplying `[[gnu::nonnull]]` you can just remove it from the free `closer` function above and use that to avoid the warning.

Answer (score 3):

> Can we add attributes to standard function declarations without breaking standard?

There are not (yet) any attributes in standard C so you cannot use them and remain standard compliant/portable. Upcoming C23 plans to add a few attributes.

Furthermore identifiers with 2 leading underscore like `__stream` are reserved for the standard library (ISO 9899:2018 7.1.3) so unless you are writing a C standard library, you shouldn't name your identifiers like that. As a rule of thumb, they shouldn't start with an underscore at all.

Comment: It's not OP that's added the attribute but glibc 2.38. The declaration in the question is from that implementation.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Well obviously compiling glibc as pure standard C isn't a brilliant idea. There should be build instructions along with the project. Parts of the standard lib internals are impossible to implement as conforming C and there is no requirement that said internals must be written in (strict) C.

Comment: As for making the public API of the standard library non-conforming, well that's not a brilliant idea either, but a design mistake.

Comment: I just built glibc 2.38 according to the instructions and installed it. The result is what OP showed.  The expansion of `__nonnull ((1))` becomes an attribute when compilers that can handle the attribute uses glibc, otherwise it expands to nothing. It seems the problem is that template type parameters in g++ and clang++ can't carry that attribute (and a few more), so they drop it from the template type and issue a warning about that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That seems like a more complete answer than mine. It's so tiresome that the whole GNU camp are hellbent on always using as many non-standard extensions as possible just for the heck of it. If the extension was written proper, it would be hidden behind a `#pragma` as recommended by standard C itself - that's the whole reason `#pragma` exists. Now as for why glibc had to use the extension in the first place, that's a good question. I think the bug report here should be directed to glibc, not gcc/clang.